# why does update_attribute not work here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does update attribute not work here? If it shouldn't be used at the model level, then what could I use instead to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish below?

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title

  def getNewTitle qid
    if qid.is_a? Integer
     "new question title"
    end
  end

  # should only have to run it once
  def updateTitles
    Question.all.each do |q|
      begin
        newTitle = getNewTitle q.id

        if newTitle
          q = Question.find(q.id)

          q.update_attribute(:title => newTitle)
        end

      rescue
        puts "======================error======================"
      end
    end 
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you also include what is not working?  What is the error?

Comment: Can you update the question to follow Rails style guide? Here is one right here: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update_attribute` takes in two arguments. attribute name and value

```
q.update_attribute(:title, newTitle)
```

What you have is the syntax for `update_attributes`

```
q.update_attributes(:title => newTitle)
```

rails convention is to use underscores instead of camelCase for method names and variable names

Eg, `new_title, update_titles`

Answer (score 0):

As Vimsha noted, `update_attribute` takes two arguments.

But at the risk of being voted down, I would offer an alternative-- use `update`.  `update_attribute` bypasses validation, using `update` will ensure that your changes pass validation before saving.

For example:

```ruby
Question.all.each do |q|
  begin
    newTitle = getNewTitle q.id

    if newTitle
      Question.update(q.id, title: newTitle)
    end

  rescue
    puts "======================error======================"
  end
end
```

---

**API references**
for [`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update) and [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute)